# Select rows for column value from CSV java

Tags: java, csv, row, apache-commons-csv

I have a CSV ordered based on the value of the "url" column. 
I would like to select the first three rows for each "url" value. 
If the rows, for the url value, are less than 3 (2 or 1), I would like to select them anyway.

The starting CSV is the following:

```
 url;review;priority;length
 zonk-di-brigada-igor-torino;"Ora sono tornati i vecchi gestori.";0;15
 zonk-di-brigada-igor-torino;"Buona qualità dei prodotti.";0;13
 zonk-di-brigada-igor-torino;"Ultimamente però l'apericena è scaduto.";0;13
 zonk-di-brigada-igor-torino;"I coktail sono buoni.";0;11
 zonk-di-brigada-igor-torino;"Per non parlare dei cocktail.";0;10
 zonk-di-brigada-igor-torino;"Locale molto bello.";0;7
 zichella-torino;"Che pasticceria";1;19
 zichella-torino;"Bar pasticceria di classe.";1;18
```

I want to obtain:

```
 url;review
 zonk-di-brigada-igor-torino;"Ora sono tornati i vecchi gestori."
 zonk-di-brigada-igor-torino;"Buona qualità dei prodotti."
 zonk-di-brigada-igor-torino;"Ultimamente però l'apericena è scaduto."
 zichella-torino;"Che pasticceria"
 zichella-torino;"Bar pasticceria di classe."
```

I started with this code but selects only one row.

```
 ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
 String url, text;
 for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParserMatrix) 
 {
   url = csvRecord.get("url");
   text = csvRecord.get("review");
   if(!urls.contains(url))
   {
        urls.add(url);
        bw.write(url+";"+'"'+text+'"'+"\n");
   }
 }
```

Comment: What CSV-processing library are you using? Add a Tag or a mention.

Comment: apache commons csv

Comment: Post that information as an edit to your Question rather than as a Comment. Your audience should not have to trawl through comments to make sense of your Question. Also, notice how I added a Tag as well.